# Hit test on matrix manipulated rectangle

Tags: android, matrix

I have a bitmap image that I'm trying to do a hit test on. The hit test works if its just a normal bitmap. But I need to rotate and scale the bitmap and I just can't seem to figure out the hit test properly.

x and y here are the cursor x and y. I need to check if the cursor (finger press) was clicked inside the manipulated bitmap. The scale seems to work fine, but the rotation doesn't seem to take affect.

```
float[] pts = new float[4];
float left = m.getX();
float top = m.getY();
float right = left + mBitmaps.get(i).getWidth();
float bottom = top + mBitmaps.get(i).getHeight();
pts[0] = left;
pts[1] = top;
pts[2] = right;
pts[3] = bottom;

float midx = left + mBitmaps.get(i).getWidth()/2;
float midy = top + mBitmaps.get(i).getHeight()/2;

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setRotate(m.getRotation(), midx, midy);
matrix.setScale(m.getSize(), m.getSize(), midx, midy);

matrix.mapPoints(pts);

if(x >= pts[0] && x <= pts[2] && y >= pts[1] && y <= pts[3])
{
    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test fails because after rotation the rectangle is no longer aligned to the coordinate axes.

A trick you can do is to transform the cursor position back with the inverse transformation matrix and then compare the transformed position with the original rectangle.

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setRotate(m.getRotation(), midx, midy);
matrix.postScale(m.getSize(), m.getSize(), midx, midy);

Matrix inverse = new Matrix();
matrix.invert(inverse);
pts[0] = x;
pts[1] = y;
inverse.mapPoints(pts);
if(pts[1] >= top && pts[1] <= bottom && pts[0] >= left && pts[0] <= right)
{
    return i;
}
```

Comment: I think the test should be if (pts[0] >= 0 && pts[0] < bitmap.getWidth() && pts[1] >= 0 && pts[1] < bitmap.getHeight())

Comment: @yoah I don't think so, there is no translation in the matrix.

Comment: @Henry Using your suggest and the cursor just acts as if the bitmap hadn't been transformed. Meaning if its rotated 90 degrees, the hit area doesn't reflect that. Its still as if the bitmap had not been rotated.

Comment: @lostdev this can only be if the bitmap rotation is not correctly captured in your `matrix`. I will add the matrix setup code to the answer.

Comment: Yeah that's what I have, I didn't remove that code. I simply added yours to mine.

Comment: Can you check if `m.getRotation()` gives the correct rotation?

Comment: Yes it is 125 degrees on the test I just did.

Comment: Found it, the `setScale` had overwritten the rotation. See update.